# Invalid DateTime in Typescript

Tags: angular, datetime, typescript

I have a method to modify the date like this

```
private  modifyDate(dateString: string): Date {
    let formattedDate= new DatePipe(Defaults.APPLICATION_LOCALE).transform(new DateIEPipe().transform(dateString), 'shortDate');
    let newFormattedDate: Date = new Date(formattedDate);
    return newFormattedDate;
}
```

Input to this method would be like "2017-01-23T14:09:19+0100" i.e. a string

I'm using a pipe to format the string to have timezone.

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'dateIE'
})
export class DateIEPipe implements PipeTransform  {

    transform(input:String): any {

        if(input.trim() == "") return input;
        // Check if timezone present in the date string?
        let splits = input.split("+");
        let formattedTZ = "";
        if(splits.length > 1) {
            formattedTZ = splits[1].substr(0, 2).concat(":").concat(splits[1].substr(2));
            return splits[0].concat("+").concat(formattedTZ);
        } else {
            return input;
        }
    }
}
```

This pipe would return datestring like 23.01.2017 09:19. Now I want to convert this to Date so I'm trying "let newFormattedDate: Date = new Date(formattedDate);" but I'm getting it as Invalid date. How to resolve this?

Comment: what is your Defaults.APPLICATION_LOCALE..??

Comment: @VivekSingh It is for setting locale and I have set default locale to en_US

Answer (score 1):

> Based on your code I have created a [plnkr here](https://plnkr.co/edit/9bD64nQ3n0KJWm5S8MiO?p=preview) and it is giving me the required output.

Modified your private function,

```
private modifyDate(dateString: string): Date {
    let d = new DatePipe('en-US');
    return d.transform(new DateIEPipe().transform(dateString),'short');
}
```

For more info on DatePipe refer [Angular docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-pipe.html) and for [Examples here](http://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-date-pipe-example)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm expecting the output as "23.01.2017 09:19" but it's giving me thee output "Mon Jan 23 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"

Comment: I have updated the plnkr check it out...https://plnkr.co/edit/9bD64nQ3n0KJWm5S8MiO?p=preview